# Connection refused using FTP local passive mode in Android

Tags: java, android, ftp

I am currently developing an Android application that has to connect herself to a local FTP server (I am using Filezilla server).
I've downloaded the org.commons.apache.net ftp librabry.

Here is my code relative to my android project :

```
    FTPClient mFTPClient = new FTPClient();

    try {
        mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
        mFTPClient.connect("10.0.2.2", 21);

        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
            mFTPClient.login("lucas", "elie");
            mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        }

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        Log.e("TEST", "SocketException: " + e.getStackTrace().toString() + " " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.e("TEST", "UnknownHostException: " + e.getStackTrace().toString() + " " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TEST", "IOException: " + e.getStackTrace().toString() + " " + e.getMessage());
    }

    //

    FileOutputStream desFileStream;
    try {
        desFileStream = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/sample_0.jpg");
        mFTPClient.retrieveFile("/sample_0.jpg", desFileStream);
        desFileStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("TEST", "FileNotFoundException: " + e.getStackTrace().toString() + " " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TEST", "IOException: " + e.getStackTrace().toString() + " " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

The connection is working (mFTPClient.connect("10.0.2.2", 21);), as I can see it on my local server interface, but when i'm trying to download my file (mFTPClient.retrieveFile("/sample_0.jpg", desFileStream);), i'm getting an IOException in the Logcat :

04-07 11:25:26.300: E/TEST(671): IOException: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@412ca688 failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 2832): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

I precise that I added these two lines in the Android Manifest XML file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Using EXACTLY the same code, but in a classic Java project instead of an Android project, all works perfectly fine (replacing 10.0.2.2 by 127.0.0.1 and "/mnt/sdcard" by "C:\") !

Could anyone help me please?

EDIT : I found my mistake. If that can help someone, i simply had to replace 10.0.2.2 with my local IP adress (in my case 192.168.0.5)